# PHP CURL Soap Request Print Response

Tags: php, soap, curl, xmlhttprequest

Hello I am trying to send a Soap Request to powerpay.biz and am not getting a response, plus when i use my test url

https://gkicmerchants.com/admin/classes/soap-request.xml

i get this error

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/content/g/k/i/gkic1848/html/admin/classes/submit_applicant.class.php on line 299
```

Here is my code:

```
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$credentials = $username.":".$password; 
$url = "http://gkicmerchants.com/admin/classes/soap-server.php";

$soap_request = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soap:Body>
            ....
            </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>';

$header = array(
"Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/xml",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Pragma: no-cache",
"SOAPAction: '".$url."'",
"Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
);


$curl = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soap_request );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

// perform the request

$xml_result = curl_exec($curl);
// check for errors
if ($xml_result === false) {
$error_occurred = true;
}
else {

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_result);

    print_r($xml);
}
```

Is something wrong with curl_setopt options?

Comment: The error message implies that the response you're getting isn't properly formatted - have you tried echoing out `$xml_result` to see what you're actually getting back?

Comment: here is my result https://gkicmerchants.com/admin/classes/soap-request.xml

Comment: when i echo the result i get: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 18 Apr 2013 17:06:27 GMT Server: Apache Content-Length: 0 Content-Type: text/html

Comment: Then the issue is that you're not getting a response back from the server - can you get any information from the server to see what's happened there?

Comment: They said they aren't seeing any new requests from me coming in.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is `gkicmerchants.com` your site?

Comment: OK if found it wasnt the code. Response came back as Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:. SO i just need to get the right credentials from the client. Thanks

Comment: In that case, could you add it as an answer and mark it as correct when you get a chance?

Answer (score 1):

Do not include response header to the output. Drop this line:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```